# What is the best approach for asserting the json fields in rest api automation?

Tags: python, json, rest, automation, automated-tests

If my json object contains several attributes then should I write assertion for each and every attributes or is there any better way?

eg :
{'data':{'id' : 123, 'first_name' : 'bruce', 'last_name' : 'wayne', 'phone' : 12345, 'is_superhero' : 'yes', 'can_fly' : 'uses_tech', 'aka' : 'batman'}}

Now, I can write assertions as follows:

Approach 1:

assertEquals(response['data']['first_name'] == 'bruce') and so on for all the attributes, imagine if my json response have 100 fields then my test code would include 100 assertEquals.

Approach 2:

I can do the json comparison, but then how that would work when there are dynamic values(like id) which are present in json object & are bound to change every time!

If you have done API automation and made assertions on complex json objects then I'm looking forward to the approach you have followed.

I feel like there has to be a better approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest you do is using JSON Schemas, read more about it here: https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/.

Once you have the schema for your API you can validate it with a library like JSON schema, check it here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema

Furthermore you can generate the schemas from your JSON automatically with the GenSON library: https://github.com/wolverdude/GenSON. Take into account that this library has limitations and you would need to tune the schema generated to fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @enrique for the response. Looks like it can be one of the good approach. Asserting on the json Schema + the specific changed/new attributes should do. Sounds right!!